# Not counting correct characters from file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code which runs as expected but has a few issues when counting the number of characters and the length of the longest line in characters. The follwoing is my code:

```
def stats(file_name):
    n_chars = 0
    n_words = 0
    n_lines = 0
    longest_line = 0
    with open(file_name) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        n_lines = len(lines)
        longest_line = max([len(line) for line in lines])
        words = []
        line_words = [line.split() for line in lines]
        for line in line_words:
            for word in line:
                words.append(word)
        n_words = len(words)
        chars = []
        line_chars = [list(word) for word in words]
        for line in line_chars:
            for char in line:
                chars.append(char)
        n_chars = len(chars)
        f.close()
        return n_chars, n_words, n_lines, longest_line
```

Can you guys see anything that would make the code not count the correct number of characters. The longest line always appears as one more than the correct answer.

The input is the following:

BEAUTIFUL Soup, so rich and green,
Waiting in a hot tureen!
Who for such dainties would not stoop?
Soup of the evening, beautiful Soup!
Soup of the evening, beautiful Soup!

Beau--ootiful Soo-oop!
Beau--ootiful Soo-oop!
Soo--oop of the e--e--evening,
Beautiful, beautiful Soup!

Beautiful Soup! Who cares for fish,
Game, or any other dish?
Who would not give all else for two
Pennyworth only of Beautiful Soup?
Pennyworth only of beautiful Soup?

Beau--ootiful Soo-oop!
Beau--ootiful Soo-oop!
Soo--oop of the e--e--evening,
Beautiful, beauti--FUL SOUP!

The expected output is the following:

Characters: 553
Words: 81
Lines: 21
Longest line: 38

The actual (failed) output:

characters: 469
words: 81
lines: 21
longest: 39

Comment: When you read from a file - the newline character is retained... so you probably want to `r.strip('\n')` to remove it... I'm sure I've seen someone write a question with an attempt of doing `wc` in Python that received answers before that addressed this... I'll see if I can find it...

Comment: It might help if your question included the input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. I recommend not using the phrase "runs as expected" and "has a few issues" in one question. Either it runs as expected or it has issues, but not both at the same time.

Comment: My bad I forgot to add the outputs. I don't think r.strip is needed as my answer is lower than the actual correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only count the non-whitespace characters. Probably the wanted number of characters include whitespaces.

```
def stats(file_name):
    n_chars = 0
    n_words = 0
    longest_line = 0
    with open(file_name) as lines:
        for n_lines, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
            longest_line = max(longest_line, len(line.rstrip('\n'))
            n_chars += len(line)
            n_words += len(line.split())
    return n_chars, n_words, n_lines, longest_line
```

Comment: This return the number of characters correctly, but still returns the longest line as one less than it should be.

Comment: seems, that longest line is without the newline character.

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct number of characters, you have to count spaces as well as the other characters. Otherwise you'll get much smaller value. Something like:

```
n_chars = sum( [len(line) for line in lines] )
```